Average orientation of a rotating rod or decomposing an unpolarized light source in 3D into planewaves
I want to simulate the scattering spectrum of nanorods in solution. Hence, lots of particles swimming around and rotating randomly. The measured spectrum would be an average of optical responses over all possible orientations of the rods in 3D. In my simulation software I can look at the scattering spectrum of a single rod. I can change its orientation in 3D, I can excite them with a planewave (linearly polarized light) from arbitrary directions.
Let's look at the 2D-case first, where the rod's long axis rotates in the x-y-plane. If we send only one planewave propagating in z-direction in, the response oscillates like a cosine, depending on the angle between rod orientation and light polarization. It is maximal, if polarization and long-axis-orientation are parallel and minimal, if they are perpendicular. To get a response equivalent to the unpolarized or randomly oriented case, there are two possibilities:

Set a 45° angle between polarization and rod orientation
Send in two planewaves perpendicular to each other (e.g. x- and y-polarization), then the rod orientation should not matter

I would like to generalize this to 3D rotations, but cannot figure out how. One thing to consider is, that if we send in x-polarized light and let the rod rotate in the x-z-plane, its response also oscillates with a cosine. However the minimum (when it's aligned with the z-axis) is not the same as the minimum in the 2D case (when it's aligned with the y-axis).
So I would need the answer to one of these two questions:

When sending in only one planewave (e.g. x-polarized propagating in z-direction), what's the orientation vector of a single rod, whose optical response corresponds to the average over all random orientations?
Is there a (small) set of planewaves (any direction and polarization) that can be used to achieve the same?

As a bit of a gut feeling I thought aligning the rod with the x-axis and sending in three planewaves in x-, y- and z-direction, with polarizations of 45° in the respective planes (i.e. y-z, x-z & x-y) could be it, but I'm not fully convinced. The reasoning would be one beam for every rotation axis of the rod, whose polarisation is the average in the respective plane. This would be equivalent to 6 planewaves from all possible combinations of (x,y,z). Also I don't want to "overweight" some orientations by choosing redundant planewaves.
Many thanks for your help.
